# Shadow mapping does not work correctly using GLSL shaders

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, shadows, shadow-mapping

I'm a beginner in shadow mapping. I have in my scene two meshes : a cube and a floor. The scene is lighted by a single point light.

Here's for the following display the light properties :

```
lightFrustrum->setFovy(70.0f);
lightFrustrum->setAspectRatio(500.0f/500.0f);
lightFrustrum->setNearClipDistance(0.1f);
lightFrustrum->setFarClipDistance(1000.0f);
lightFrustrum->setPosition(glm::vec4(-20.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
lightFrustrum->setOrientation(glm::vec3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
lightFrustrum->setUpVectorDirection(glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

And the depth texture dimensions :

```
width = 512
height = 512
```

And the code to load the depth texture :

```
GLfloat border[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,1.0f};

glGenTextures(1, &this->m_TextId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->m_TextId);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24,
    this->m_Width, this->m_Height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, border);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LESS);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

But I have the strange display like below :

[image]

As you can see, there's two problems : there's on the bottom of the screen a black strip. And on the left of the correct shadow, there's an other smallest one which should not be here either.

Now if I put the light just above the cube at 0.0f, 15.0f, 0.0f with the same depth texture propertiesI have the following result :

[image]

And now the same light properties but a depth texture with a width and a height of 64.

[image]

The shadow seems to be correct now but if I keep the same depth texture properties but I put the light at position -20.0f, 15.0f, 0.0f like in the first case it looks like the first case but this time without the line strip on the bottom.

[image]

Here's in the vertex shader for the first pass (depth texture creation):

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f);
}
```

The vertex shader for the second pass :

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 VertexTexture;

uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 ShadowMatrix;

out vec3 Position;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 ShadowCoords;

void main(void)
{
    TexCoords = VertexTexture;
    Normal = normalize(NormalMatrix * VertexNormal);
    Position = vec3(ModelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f)).xyz;
    ShadowCoords = ShadowMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f);
}
```

And the fragment shader for the second pass :

```
#version 400

in vec3 Position;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoords;
in vec4 ShadowCoords;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D Tex1;
uniform sampler2DShadow ShadowMap;
uniform int lightCount;

struct PointLight
{
    vec4 Position;
    vec3 La, Ld, Ls;
    float Kc, Kl, Kq;
};

struct Material
{
    vec3 Ka, Kd, Ks, Ke;
    float Shininess;
};

uniform PointLight LightInfos[10];
uniform Material MaterialInfos;

vec3 Basic_ADS_Phong_Shading(int idx, vec3 normal, vec3 lightDir)
{
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(-Position.xyz);

    vec3 Ambient = LightInfos[idx].La * MaterialInfos.Ka;
    vec3 Diffuse = LightInfos[idx].Ld * MaterialInfos.Kd * max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0f);
    vec3 Specular = LightInfos[idx].Ls * MaterialInfos.Ks * pow(max(dot(reflectDir, viewDir), 0.0f), MaterialInfos.Shininess);
    vec3 Emissive = MaterialInfos.Ke;

    return (Ambient + Diffuse + Specular + Emissive);
}

vec3 getLightIntensity(void)
{
    vec3 LightIntensity = vec3(0.0f);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < lightCount; idx++)
    {
        vec3 tnorm = (gl_FrontFacing ? -normalize(Normal) : normalize(Normal));
        vec3 lightDirNorm = vec3(0.0f);

        if (LightInfos[idx].Position.w == 0.0f)
            lightDirNorm = normalize(vec3(LightInfos[idx].Position));
        else if (LightInfos[idx].Position.w == 1.0f)
        {
            vec3 lightDir = vec3(LightInfos[idx].Position) - Position;
            lightDirNorm = normalize(lightDir);
            LightIntensity = Basic_ADS_Phong_Shading(idx, -tnorm, lightDirNorm);
        }
    }
    return (LightIntensity);
}

void main(void)
{
    vec4 Ambient = vec4(LightInfos[0].La * MaterialInfos.Ka, 1.0f);
    vec4 LightIntensity = vec4(getLightIntensity(), 1.0f);

    vec4 TexColor = texture(Tex1, TexCoords);
    float shadow = textureProj(ShadowMap, ShadowCoords);

    if (TexColor != 0)
        FragColor = LightIntensity * TexColor * shadow + Ambient * TexColor;
    else
        FragColor = LightIntensity * shadow + Ambient;
}
```

So I really lost in front of this situation. Does anyone have had the same problem using shadow mapping ? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: For one thing, your border color does not make a whole lot of sense. You basically want anything outside of the normalized texture coordinate range to map to your clear depth; why you chose to use 0.0f for the blue channel I do not know. But really, this can be handled much better in shaders - speaking of which, where are yours? The texture setup is only a small portion of the real problem.

Comment: I fixed the blue channel color to 1.0f but it's the same result. I updated the post by adding the shaders I use for the first pass (render the scene from light point of view) and the second pass (render the scene from the camera). Do you see something wrong ? Do you think it could be a problem with the size of the depth texture or a matrix problem ? I don't think so because the main shadow is correct... Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

1. You should set your far plane to infinity for shadows, instead of setting a far clip distance of 1000.
2. Also, for a ratio of far/near of 1000.0/0.1 you would get better precision with a far plane at infinity anyway. Check this paper out http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/UD12.pdf ("3 - Projection Matrix Precision").